# JMH - ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList

Tags: java, maven, jar, benchmarking, jmh

When using JMH with maven to benchmark a project that was previously working and benchmarking as intended experiencing the following error:

```
java -jar target/benchmarks.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.AbstractResourceReader.getReaders(AbstractResourceReader.java:98)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkList.find(BenchmarkList.java:122)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.internalRun(Runner.java:260)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:209)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(Main.java:71)
```

I have seen other similar posts which were solved by performing a mvn clean install but I have already done this repeatedly.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm running into the same error trying to run JMH without Maven